# Qt Creator and git - where is the repository

Tags: git, qt, github

I once set up a local repository git repository and opened a Qt project there, using Qt Creator.

I am embarrassed to say, even with lots of googling, I can't work out what I did back then :-/

If I go to Qt Creator and commit my project it knows which files are changed and performs commits to a local repo. But where is it?

How can I find this out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a .git directory in Qt. It'll have a config file in it with all the relevant info in it.

Comment: Sorry, which qt directory?

Comment: Search for the .git sub directory in your project's directory.

Comment: Probably the root; whatever directory you're in when you commit.

Comment: Let's take it to chat

Comment: Sure, thanks! ummmm, oh... how do I do that?
Edit: I have created a room for us. do i have to invite you?

Comment: Just saw this, sorry. I'm there now and lurking.